# Can I have two different packages in same Android application?

Tags: android

I have two different applications doing different things. Now I'm creating an application in which main.xml will have only two buttons and each button click will open one of these application.

I want to include these two applications' code along with their packages to my this application [for some reasons I really do not want to change their packaga names]. Is it possible?

Will manifest file creation need any non-trivial changes?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have two different packages in your application.